# Создание своего дизайна Android

Tags: android

Нужно сделать уникальный интересный интерфейс для приложения.

Но я не знаю с чего начать.

Подскажите пожалуйста: что нужно подучить (имею ввиду, какой раздел например `style` или что-то другое), на что обратить внимание и что изучить,  чтобы сделать красивый дизайн?

*П.С.*

*Если у кого есть - то прошу подробное(или не очень) руководство (с чего начать и чем продолжить).*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Посмотрите Google [Material Design](https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html).

Пролистать придётся всё – посмотреть анимации, иллюстрации хотя бы, примерно запомнить, где о чём идёт речь. Там не так много.

Потом определите самый основной, часто используемый путь пользователя в вашем приложении, и набросайте экраны к нему, совсем примерно придерживаясь рекомендаций выше.

Затем уточняйте и детализируйте.

Comment: что , по вашему мнению , есть здесь главным для новичка и с чего начать ?

Comment: обновил ответ. Там не так много – пролистайте всё. И для приложения попробуйте найти библиотеки с готовыми компонентами в стиле Material Design. От общего – к частному. Размер теней в последнюю очередь, но, тем не менее, обязательно )

Comment: спасибо! 
Начну с самого начала и пойду по порядку.

Answer (score 2):

В https://www.google.com/design/spec/material-design/introduction.html Обратите внимание в нервую очередь на разделы Components и Patterns

Comment: если изучить эти два раздела - то я буду в курсе дела, чтобы более-менее сделать нормальный интерфейс ?

Comment: Нужно обратить внимание на все разделы, просто в этих разделах я думаю основное, что вам пригодится)